# Want to learn to create Dynamic sites

Tags: programming-languages

I want to create dynamic sites.. Which language should I use - PHP/Python/Perl/Ruby ??

I wanna make search engines & social networks...

Thanks...

- do also refer me tutorials...

Comment: So, you want to build a combination google/facebook? Alas, that's really not enough to go on to recommend a particular language.

Comment: @DA then refer a list or something like that??

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information. For starters, what are you programming with now?

Comment: @Marchin Currently I'm learning HTML/CSS and will soon start with some JavaScript... I'm also a starter at C++ ..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make good, well-performing search engines and social network sites, you have a lot of work ahead of you and the choice of programming language is one of the least of your concerns.  Use what you're comfortable with and what has the tooling to allow you to work efficiently.  If you don't know any of the languages yet, I'd recommend looking at Python and Ruby first.   They have good tools (Django, Rails), and have notable performance attention dedicated to them (and with Ruby, you can run on JRuby, where you can piggyback on all of Java's performance and deployment work).

However, there are a lot bigger problems you will need to solve than your programming language.

- Server architecture - web server, database, caching, replication
- Code architecture - use a framework, don't repeat yourself
- Social design - how does your social network operate? What are the various actions and their meanings?  #1 mistake is to just replicate Facebook's decisions without thinking about what the best decision is for *your domain*.  What works for Facebook may well not work for you - you need to think through how the site will operate.<sup>1</sup>
- Search indexing - if you're building a search engine, where does your index come from? Do you use a third-party index, or do you crawl and build your own? Building the crawler will also be a lot of hard work.  You may need to drop to C or C++ for parts of the crawling and indexing system if you're working in any of the languages you mentioned.

Short story: there's a lot of things to think about, and in the greater scheme your choice of language among the ones you mentioned is largely immaterial.  Pick what you're comfortable with and go with it.  Expect to spend a lot of time learning.  It sounds like you have limited programming experience - I would recommend picking some much smaller projects and trying to make them work.  And follow the advice of smart programmers - [teach yourself programming in ten years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

<sup>1</sup>I'd argue that their decisions don't really work for Facebook either, but that's another story.

Comment: HTML and CSS+ some Javascript is essential for most projects. Then comes dynamic sites I wanna create, for that, Is python better or PHP? I'm learning C++ from a week.

Comment: I personally think Python is far better than PHP (IMO, the only reason to use PHP is because you already know it or you are extending code in it; for a new project, use something else).